# How can i show all processes memory usage faster?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

The problem is that I need to loop each over all the processes.
For example in task manager it looks like it's updating all the processes memory usage very fast maybe every second or less.

I have a backgroundworker dowork event:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            while (true)
            {
                completed = true;
                if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                  GetProcessesMemoryUsage();
                }
            }
        }
```

The method GetProcessesMemoryUsage:

```
private void GetProcessesMemoryUsage()
{

 foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
            {
              if (File.Exists(p.MainModule.FileName))
                    {
                     Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(p.ProcessName);

                        PerformanceCounter performanceCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
                        performanceCounter.CategoryName = "Process";
                        performanceCounter.CounterName = "Working Set";
                        performanceCounter.InstanceName = processes[0].ProcessName;
                        memoryUsage = ((uint)performanceCounter.NextValue() / 1024).ToString("N0");
                    }
           }
```

The problem it need to make the foreach loop all the time to update the memory usage of each process.

Then how does it working in task manager ? How they are updating all the processes so fast ?

Comment: It's probably listening to events and reacting to them (it may be using multiple threads too). I doubt it's doing a foreach loop internally

Comment: I would guess that Task Manager uses WMI directly to query the counters for all processes simultaneously. Your loop queries them one at a time.

Comment: Have you timed this? Is it actually slow?

Comment: I'd guess the File.Exists call is the bottleneck in this code...

Comment: For a faster implementation, you can try to use `Parallels.ForEach(Process.GetProcesses(), (Process p) => { .... })`

Answer (score 0):

On my box the initial construction of the PerformanceCounter including the first call to NextValue takes the most time, over and over again. You can use a Stopwatch class to investigate this your self.

If I however keep the created PerformanceCounter instances around, the performance of NextValue gets way better, around a fifth of the time it takes on the first call.

A naïve first approach to see if this is enough in your scenario you could do something like this:

```
    private List<PerformanceCounter> pclist = new List<PerformanceCounter>();
    private void GetProcessesMemoryUsage()
    {
        // if our list is empty, populate
        if (pclist.Count == 0)
        {
            // this takes around 300 ms on my box after running this a couple of times
            foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
            {
                if (File.Exists(p.MainModule.FileName))
                {
                    Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(p.ProcessName);

                    PerformanceCounter performanceCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
                    performanceCounter.CategoryName = "Process";
                    performanceCounter.CounterName = "Working Set";
                    performanceCounter.InstanceName = processes[0].ProcessName;
                    pclist.Add(performanceCounter);

                }
            }
        }
        // this takes only around 80 msec on my box
        foreach(var pc in pclist)
        {
             memoryUsage = ((uint)pc.NextValue() / 1024).ToString("N0");
        }

    }
```

This does mean that you now need some extra code to watch for processes that are terminated so you can remove those from the List. That is something that can be asked in a new question.